# How to undo a modification in Linux if Linux won't start due to the modification?

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I created a `.bashrc` file in the `/home` directory and then rebooted Linux
but now it wont restart.

I am now on a Live CD version of Linux.

Why are many folders not accessible?

Comment: Are you running as the superuser? If not, you wouldn't have access to all files/folders. Have a look at `su`/`sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're now using a Live CD, just delete the problematic `.bashrc` file and reboot into your normal Linux installation.

Comment: i see the .bashrc but it wont let me delete it or edit it.

Comment: @user2204072 What error do you get?

Comment: the "Delete" option is not selectable.

Comment: @user2204072 Which distribution of Live CD are you using? Are you sure you're not trying to delete the Live CD's `/home/.bashrc`? You need to delete the `/mnt`'d Linux's file.

Comment: Have you tried `rm /path/to/.bashrc` in shell?

Comment: it appears i had to select "open as administrator" and then i was able to delete the stuff in it. i just rebooted and it's working great.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to a Live CD and delete the file. You may need to mount your drive as read write.

To find your drive ID, run `df -h`. You're looking for something like `/dev/sda1`. Then run

```
mkdir foo
sudo mount /dev/sda1 -o remount,rw foo/
sudo rm foo/home/your_user/.bashrc
```

replacing `/dev/sda1` with your device ID.